# Thread priority at Windows, have no matters?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, operating-system

I was getting fun with threads priority and affinity. What I was doing that, I saw at least one problem - when I use only one CPU, threads are not getting enought processor time. For example I have here some result of my observation.

https://pastebin.com/2fgPwMbw

First column is time in ms, second one is a counter when thread have priority equal 0, third and fourth is counter when priority is -1, and fifth and sixth is counter when priority is -2.
And It is my code:

```
DWORD WINAPI thread( void* counter )
{
DWORD* local = ( DWORD* )counter;

    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            suma += sin( i );
        }
        ++(*local);
        suma = 0;
    }
}


int main( )
{
    DWORD_PTR affinity = 1;

    SetProcessAffinityMask( GetCurrentProcess( ), affinity );

    LPDWORD counters = ( LPDWORD )calloc( THREADS, sizeof( DWORD ) );

    int normalPriorityIndex = 0;
    int lowPriorityIndex[2] = { 1, 2 };
    int idlePriorityIndex[2] = { 3, 4 };

    HANDLE hw[THREADS] = {
        CreateThread( 0, 0, thread, counters + normalPriorityIndex, 0, 0 ),
        CreateThread( 0, 0, thread, counters + lowPriorityIndex[0], 0, 0 ),
        CreateThread( 0, 0, thread, counters + lowPriorityIndex[1], 0, 0 ),
        CreateThread( 0, 0, thread, counters + idlePriorityIndex[0], 0, 0 ),
        CreateThread( 0, 0, thread, counters + idlePriorityIndex[1], 0, 0 ),
    };

    SetThreadPriority( hw[normalPriorityIndex], 0 );
    SetThreadPriority( hw[lowPriorityIndex[0]], -1 );
    SetThreadPriority( hw[lowPriorityIndex[1]], -1 );
    SetThreadPriority( hw[idlePriorityIndex[0]], -2 );
    SetThreadPriority( hw[idlePriorityIndex[1]], -2 );

    FILE* file;
    char* fileName = ( char* )calloc( 32, sizeof( char ) );
    fileName = "dane.txt";
    fopen_s( &file, fileName, "w" );

    DWORD startTime = GetTickCount( );
    FILE* stream = stdout;

    while (!_kbhit( ))
    {
        if (GetTickCount( ) - startTime > 600000)
        {
            break;
        }
        fprintf( file, "%5.ld  |  ", GetTickCount( ) - startTime );
        fprintf( file, "%ld  %ld  %ld  %ld  %ld\n",
            counters[normalPriorityIndex], 
            counters[lowPriorityIndex[0]],
            counters[lowPriorityIndex[1]],
            counters[idlePriorityIndex[0]], 
            counters[idlePriorityIndex[1]] );
        Sleep( 750 );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        CloseHandle( hw[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Why threads with priority -2 have bigger counter, then thread with priority -1...?

Comment: Profiling this is very difficult.  If you do it right then it makes no difference at all.  Doing it wrong is *very* easy, what matters is what other programs on the machine are doing.  Something trivial like the machine getting a network packet changes the result.

Comment: Well, there is somethng odd here.  Assuming that the set affinity works, (never used it), then I would expect that the four threads below normalPriority would only get occasional, and very limited, CPU access via the anti-starvation algorithm.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit, by my figuring, all four low-priority threads together only got about 2.75% as much CPU time as the normal-priority thread.  So "occasional, and very limited" sounds about right. :-)

Comment: As for the original question, I believe the answer is that the anti-starvation mechanism doesn't differentiate between starved threads of different priorities.  (Nor is it required to be otherwise fair, though as Hans says I'm not sure your results are necessarily meaningful.)  If you change your normal-priority thread to relinquish the CPU for say 10% of the time then you should see the -1 threads getting significantly more of that extra time than the -2 threads do.

Comment: Regarding SetProcessAffinityMask: The first available processor is not necessarily at bit 0. Use GetProcessAffinityMask first to get the available processors/bits, then select one of the bits that GetProcessAffinityMask returns.